# Get Current Page Name to Prestashop 1.7 Module

Tags: smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm currently working on a Prestashop 1.7.1.0 module targeted at clothing sites. I need to get the **exact page name the user's currently browsing** such as 'index', 'Women', 'Tops', 'T-shirts', **into the module**. 
I tried using Smarty global variables for this but those seem to be removed for this version.

Any suggestions & help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

To get this in a tpl, the new variable in 1.7 version to do this is as follows:

```
{$page.page_name}

Instead of:

{$page_name}
```

You can use this in any tpl of your module.

It works for me in a Prestashop 1.7 module I created, however I can't get other global smarty variables, i.e. shop_name, lang_iso, etc...

Comment: Hi,  here you have all the new global variables: http://victor-rodenas.com/variables-globales-en-prestashop-1-7/

Answer (score 2):

FrontController load page options and assign it.

You can get it in tpl with {$page}

```
        Array
(
    [title] => 
    [canonical] => 
    [meta] => Array
        (
            [title] => 'title'
            [description] => 
            [keywords] => 
            [robots] => index
        )
[page_name] => 'page name is here'
[body_classes] => Array
    (
        [lang-es] => 1
        [lang-rtl] => 
        [country-ES] => 1
        [currency-EUR] => 1
        [layout-full-width] => 1
        [page-] => 1
        [tax-display-enabled] => 1
        [pm_details_layout1] => 1
        [header_static] => 1
    )

[admin_notifications] => Array


      (
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST}{$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI}
```

You can try this code i think its working...

Comment: Afraid I didn't have any luck with the Smarty code.
I managed to implement a solution for this using php $_SERVER array itself. I'll be posting it as an answer here for reference by others.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get Smarty functions to work on my module but I managed to code a simple solution using PHP $_SERVER array functions. I'll be posting the code below for the reference of others.

```
$protocol = null;
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") 
{
    $protocol = 'https';
} 
else 
{
    $protocol = 'http';
}
$port = "";
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80")
{
    $port = ":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"];
}
$currentPageUrl =  $protocol."://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$port.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo '<b>Current Page URL : </b>' . $currentPageUrl . "<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

To get this in a tpl, the new variable in 1.7 version to do this is:

```
{$page.page_name}
```

Instead of:

```
{$page_name}
```

You can use this in any tpl of your module.

Hope it help's you

Answer (score 0):

you can also find out the page name using js/jQuery

```
console.log(prestashop.page.page_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

$currentPage = $this->context->controller->php_self;